# Signed APK cannot open With multiDexKeepProguard

Tags: java, android, apk, signed

```
 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
2020-10-18 10:16:02.419 29711-29711/? E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method b(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; in class Landroid/content/res/XmlResourceParser; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
        at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.g(Unknown Source:44)
        at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.d(Unknown Source:13)
        at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source:13)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6983)
```

I already added but not working.

```
-keep class org.xmlpull.v1.** { *;}
-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**
```

This is Gradle file with multiDexKeepProguard file('multidex-config.pro')

```
 
        release {

            minifyEnabled true 
          
            shrinkResources true


            debuggable false

            multiDexKeepProguard file('multidex-config.pro')
}
```